# Building a secure file-manager app with Django

Tags: python, django, file-manager

I'm developing a project which is going to be a public website and it needs to get media files (digital images, audios and videos) from users and save them and I don't want users to upload malicious files into my server (I'm currently using an SFTP server for storage). So I'm looking for a solution to check file formats and allow "safe and intact" media files to be uploaded.

Is there any python package to check some bytes of the file and say "this is a valid jpg" or "mp3" etc? Can you recommend any other solution for my problem (securing my file-manager app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [python-magic](https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic), here the example of guessing the original jpg file with pdf file with jpg extension.

```
def file_path_mime(file_path):
    mime = magic.from_file(file_path, mime=True)
    return mime


def check_in_memory_mime(in_memory_file):
    mime = magic.from_buffer(in_memory_file.read(), mime=True)
    return mime
file_path_mime('/path/to/sneaky_pdf_file.jpg')

>> 'application/pdf'

file_path_mime('path/to/a_file.jpg'):

>> 'image/jpg'
```

you can install it by typing command pip install python-magic

Comment: This works pretty cool. I changed the postfix of the file to test if it can recognize file format correctly and it did. Thank you.